# g++ unknown /tmp/cc21HhMd.o: In function `main::{lambda( compilation error

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, g++, c++14

i try to compile using g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)
some open source simple server which is using uvlib which i compiled successfully 
this is the github repository :

https://github.com/Matheus28/ws28

this is the compilation command :

```
g++  echo.cpp -Wall -O0 -g -std=c++1y -I/home/vagrant/libuv/include -Isrc -L/home/vagrant/libuv/build -lssl -lcrypto -luv
```

but it gives me compilation error :

```
/tmp/cc21HhMd.o: In function `main::{lambda(ws28::Client*, char const*, unsigned long, int)#4}::operator()(ws28::Client*, char const*, unsigned long, int) const':
/home/vagrant/ws28/echo.cpp:36: undefined reference to `ws28::Client::Send(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char)'
/tmp/cc21HhMd.o: In function `main::{lambda(uv_timer_s*)#6}::operator()(uv_timer_s*) const':
/home/vagrant/ws28/echo.cpp:58: undefined reference to `ws28::Server::StopListening()'
/tmp/cc21HhMd.o: In function `main':
/home/vagrant/ws28/echo.cpp:16: undefined reference to `ws28::Server::Server(uv_loop_s*, ssl_ctx_st*)'
/home/vagrant/ws28/echo.cpp:64: undefined reference to `ws28::Server::Listen(int, bool)'
/home/vagrant/ws28/echo.cpp:69: undefined reference to `ws28::Server::~Server()'
/home/vagrant/ws28/echo.cpp:69: undefined reference to `ws28::Server::~Server()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out] Error 1
```

what i dont understand is what is the line that handling this object from where did he come ?:

```
/tmp/cc21HhMd.o: In function `main::{lambda(ws28::Client*, char const*, unsigned long, int)#4}::operator()(ws28::Client*, char const*, unsigned long, int) const':
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your outer question: You still need to compile and link against the `.cpp` files in `src` in the linked GitHub repository.
You did not tell us what your build system is, but I would recommend linking the ws28 src files into a static library and linking to that.
You can then compile `echo.cpp` by linking to the static library.

Alternatively, you can simply do `g++ echo.cpp src/*.cpp ...` if you do not mind recompiling the ws28 library every time.

As for your inner question: every `[](...){...}` thing is a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). The compiler constructs an anonymous functor that has the body of the lambda as its `operator()`.
The line numbers in the error message tell you exactly which lambda needs which function.